# retrieve values from actionperformed method outside and use them globally

Tags: java, swing, setpropertyactionlistener

```
 public class QuickStart4f extends JFrame {
 JPanel myjpdraw = new JPanel();
 JButton myjbdrawnow = new JButton("DRAW NOW");
 JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Point 1 : ");
 JTextField mytf1 = new JTextField("", 5);
 JTextField mytf2 = new JTextField("", 5);
 JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Point 2 : ");
 JTextField mytf3 = new JTextField("", 5);
 JTextField mytf4 = new JTextField("", 5);
 public double pt11;
 public double pt12;
 public double pt21;
 public double pt22;

myjpdraw.add(j1);
myjpdraw.add(mytf1);
myjpdraw.add(mytf2);
myjpdraw.add(j2 );
myjpdraw.add(mytf3);
myjpdraw.add(mytf4);
myjpdraw.add(myjbdrawnow);

getContentPane().add(myjpdraw,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

myjbdrawnow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        pt11 = Double.parseDouble(mytf1.getText());
        pt12 = Double.parseDouble(mytf2.getText());
        pt21 = Double.parseDouble(mytf3.getText());
        pt22 = Double.parseDouble(mytf4.getText());
    }
});
        System.out.print(pt11);
  }
 }
```

When I am retrieving the value pt11 from the actionperformed method and trying to print it, it gives me a null value. How to get the value that has been entered in the textfield and access it outside the button actionperformed method?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In this case, you'd need to factor out the 3rd party classes in order to be the C of MCVE or the SC of SSCCE. 2) Note that the line adding an `ActionListener` to `myjbdrawnow` is commented out, so the `actionPerformed(..)` method is never called. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: I edited the question. Adding an ActionListener to myjbdrawnow is commented out which does not concern it before.

Comment: *"I edited the question."* Where are the imports? Where is the `main(..)` method? There is more to an MCVE / SSCCE than just Minimal or Short. Please **read** the linked documents rather than just glance at them.

Comment: *"When I am retrieving the value pt11 from the actionperformed method.."* Nope. that is not where/when the `System.out.print(pt11);` is happening, since it is outside the brackets of the action performed method. The print out would occur before the button is ever pressed. Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow & makes problems like this easier to solve! Every IDE offers a keyboard shortcut for formatting (indenting) code to the standard it uses.